Excel Merge Multiple Row Text Join Formula
I need to be able to Merge Multiple Rows of text bases on the value in the first two columns through a formula
See below for Data Source and Expected outcome (Updated)
Source



No.
Type
Line No.
Comment
Date




532549
Fault
1000
Case 32549 - No Output
5/25/2021


532549
Resolution
1000
Job - No Output
5/25/2021


532549
Resolution
2000
Problem - Firmware Mismatch
5/25/2021


532549
Resolution
3000
Repair - Update to Current Firmware (Unit Still Running Very
5/25/2021


532549
Resolution
4000
Old 1.1.15)
4/24/2021


532549
Resolution
5000
Note - If transmitter are on different Major firmware
5/25/2021


532549
Resolution
6000
releases they will not sync.
5/25/2021


532549
Resolution
7000
Test - Listening Test Done
5/25/2021


532549
Internal
5000
Request made to Nancy for payment on repair. SA
9/1/2023


532549
Internal
10000
follow up wp : LIV
10/11/2023


532549
Internal
20000
Customer has moved on and no longer requires the mic
10/19/2023


535656
Fault
10000
Lower network port doesn't function
10/20/2023


535656
Resolution
10000
Job - Lower Network Port Does Not Function
10/20/2023


535656
Resolution
20000
Problem - As Above



535656
Resolution
30000
Repair - Replace Ethernet Port Transformer T11000



537780
Fault
1000
BENT TEMPO FADER & NO POWER
7/13/2021


537780
Fault
2000
BENT TEMPO FADER & NO POWER
7/13/2021


537780
Fault
3000
Requires full service and repair.
7/13/2021


537780
Fault
4000
QUOTE FIRST
7/13/2021


537780
Fault
5000
Serial #: LAMP005848LW
7/23/2021


537780
Resolution
1000
Significant water damage and corrosion. Parts missing,
7/23/2021


537780
Resolution
2000
cables unplugged. Most likely not economical to repair.
7/13/2021


SVO00011
Fault
10000
The RX will intermittently show no ’ready’ LED light after an IR sync & will not
9/8/2023


SVO00011
Fault
20000
pass any audio



SVO00011
Fault
30000
Also, if an IR sync is successful and does pass audio, the low battery icon is



SVO00011
Fault
40000
shown constantly on RX display, but as full status on HH TX.



SVO00011
Resolution
10000
Job – RF Issue
11/30/2023


SVO00011
Resolution
20000
Problem – Relevant Technical Bulletin Required



SVO00011
Resolution
30000
Repair – Replace Defective Capacitor



SVO00011
Resolution
40000
Test – RF Circuit Test, Listening Test Done



SVO00011
Internal
10000
Includes SLX2 HH
9/8/2023


SVO00011
Internal
20000
pro-forma invoice issued
10/10/2023


SVO00011
Internal
30000
Please Apply Service Bulletin
10/16/2023



Expected Outcome



No.
Type
Line No.
Comment
Date




532549
Fault
1000
Case 32549 - No Output
5/25/2021


532549
Resolution
1000
Job - No OutputProblem - Firmware MismatchRepair - Update to Current Firmware (Unit Still Running VeryOld 1.1.15)Note - If transmitter are on different Major firmwarereleases they will not sync.Test - Listening Test Done
5/25/2021


532549
Internal
5000
Request made to Nancy for payment on repair. SAfollow up wp : LIVCustomer has moved on and no longer requires the mic
9/1/2023


535656
Fault
10000
Lower network port doesn't function
10/20/2023


535656
Resolution
10000
Job - Lower Network Port Does Not FunctionProblem - As AboveRepair - Replace Ethernet Port Transformer T11000
10/20/2023


537780
Fault
1000
BENT TEMPO FADER & NO POWERBENT TEMPO FADER & NO POWERRequires full service and repair.QUOTE FIRSTSerial #: LAMP005848LW
7/13/2021


537780
Resolution
1000
Significant water damage and corrosion. Parts missing,cables unplugged. Most likely not economical to repair.
7/23/2021


SVO00011
Fault
10000
The RX will intermittently show no ’ready’ LED light after an IR sync & will notpass any audioAlso, if an IR sync is successful and does pass audio, the low battery icon isshown constantly on RX display, but as full status on HH TX.
9/8/2023


SVO00011
Resolution
10000
Job – RF IssueProblem – Relevant Technical Bulletin RequiredRepair – Replace Defective CapacitorTest – RF Circuit Test, Listening Test Done
11/30/2023


SVO00011
Internal
10000
Includes SLX2 HHpro-forma invoice issuedPlease Apply Service Bulletin
9/8/2023




Please post your data as text, not image.

Updated as Table as Text

Relatively easy to do using Power Query
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table

Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range or from within sheet

When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor

Make note of the Table Name in Line 2

Paste the M Code below in place of what you see

Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.

Read the code and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

Group by No. and Type
Extract the first instance of Line No. and Date
Concatenate all the Comments, separating each line by a linefeed character.



Edit:Code change to type No. column as type any as some of the entries are text and not numbers
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"No.", type any}, {"Type", type text}, {"Line No.", Int64.Type}, {"Comment", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
        
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"No.", "Type"}, {
        {"Line No.", each [#"Line No."]{0}, Int64.Type},
        {"Comment", each Text.Combine([Comment],"#(lf)"), type text},
        {"Date", each [Date]{0}, type date}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"

Result


Hi, The Above have worked on All No. Column Data that is only a Number. Unfortunately the No. System Alters and becomes a Text & Number Hybrid Field. Please See Above for Updated Data (I should have included the SVO in initial post)

@dark_tribute381 It's only a very minor change. I assume you see an error message: DataFormat.Error: We couldn't convert to Number. The only thing you need to change is, in the #"Changed Type" step, you type that column as type any. I'll edit my answer.

Thank you! Works Perfectly for Index/Match Lookups now :)

Here is one way of accomplishing the desired output, using Excel Formulas, which works with MS365:


• Formula used in cell H37
=LET(
     _No, SourceData[No.],
     _Type, SourceData[Type],
     _No_Type, UNIQUE(HSTACK(_No,_Type)),
     _Concat, TAKE(_No_Type,,1)&"|"&DROP(_No_Type,,1),
     _Joiner, BYROW(_Concat, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(SourceData[Comment],(_No&"|"&_Type=x),"")))),
     _FirstInstance, CHOOSEROWS(HSTACK(SourceData[Line No.],SourceData[Date]),XMATCH(_Concat,_No&"|"&_Type)),
     CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(_No_Type, _Joiner, _FirstInstance),1,2,4,3,5))



Relatively simple formula and easy to understand, if one steps through each of the variables.
Convert the source range into a Structured References aka Tables and name it as SourceData
And the apply the above formula, which uses the LET() function to perform various calculations.


